# No payment methods are displaying

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

All of my payment methods seem to have disappeared, i know the correct files are being called as when i turn on template paths in the back end i see them all there but nothing is displaying. This is a new problem as i was testing the checkout just the other day and everything was working fine. If you need any of the code that is begin called let me know

These are the errors in the console

```
Failed to load resource
<li id=​"top-opc-payment" class=​"section allow">​…​</li>​<span class=​"number">​4​</span>​<h2>​Payment Information​</h2>​</li>​ opcheckout.js:61
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.website.com/js/prototype/windows/themes/magento.css
```

Has anybody had this problem before and know how to fix it as i am at a loose end.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, Your opcheckout.js is not found or its having some issues. Are u getting any errors in console.?

```
class Sundar_payment_Model_Activpayment
   {

public function getActivPaymentMethods()
{
   $payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

   $methods = array(array('value'=>'', 'label'=>Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('--Please Select--')));

   foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
        $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
        $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
            'label'   => $paymentTitle,
            'value' => $paymentCode,
        );
    }

    return $methods;

}
```

}

Check this function's output and get back to me,This function echos all your enabled payment methods.

Comment: I have added my console errors to my question

Comment: Edited the answer Adam Allen